# Computing a value inside \setcounter

Tags: counters

I am using an `enumerate` list. I often want to decrement the counter of a list, to get output like this:

```
1. Some text here
2. Some more text here
2. This is a re-use of the number
3. The counter increments
3. Decrement the counter just before this \item
```

I hoped to do `\setcounter{enumi}{\value{enumi}+1}`, but it doesn't do the arithmetic, it simply writes `+1` in the PDF output.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You may want to use the `\addtocounter` instruction -- specifically, `\addtocounter{enumi}{-1}` -- to achieve your objective. The following MWE shows how this may be done.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Some text here
\item Some more text here
\addtocounter{enumi}{-1}
\item This is a re-use of the number
\item The counter increments
\addtocounter{enumi}{-1}
\item Decrement the counter just before this \texttt{\textbackslash item}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

If you find yourself executing `\addtocounter{enumi}{-1}` frequently, you may want to create a shortcut macro called, say, `\decri` (short for "decrement item counter") in your document's preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\decri}{\addtocounter{@enumctr}{-1}}
\makeatother
```

The advantage of this definition is that `\decri` will work automatically on `enumi`, `enumii`, etc. as necessary, depending on the depth of the current enumeration list. I.e., it's not necessary to provide separate macros to decrement LaTeX's first-level, second-level, etc enumeration counters. Acknowledgment: I owe this point about working on `@enumctr` to @egreg.

Comment: If you use `\@enumctr` instead of `enumi` for defining `\decri`, then the command will work at any level of enumerate.